# Python Pandas - Unknown engine: c

Tags: c, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to run the following code but I receive the error message `ValueError: Unknown engine: c`

Do I need to install something or?

```
sample = pd.read_excel(filePath, nrows=100)
float_cols = [c for c in sample if sample[c].dtype == "float64"]
float32_cols = {c: np.float32 for c in float_cols}

mainFile= pd.read_excel(filePath, engine='c', dtype=float32_cols)
```

Comment: What version of panda, what minor version of Python 3.x and what OS?

Comment: python 3.5.1 anaconda distribution, windows 7, pandas 18.1

Comment: Try saying `engine='python'` instead, or omitting that argument.

Comment: "engine: string, default None // 
If io is not a buffer or path, this must be set to identify io. Acceptable values are None or xlrd"

Comment: @ayhan, could you post it as an answer - it might help another people in future? Beside that this answer will not remain unanswered...

Comment: @MaxU I am not sure if it's an appropriate answer because I don't know why Aran thinks there is a c engine (if this is code from elsewhere, something deprecated etc).

Comment: the issue is that the dtype provides a list... with the `engine='python` method this dtype is not provided.